# Google action console simulator request and response tab not working when using custom action.json

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I have the problem that the google home/assitant action console simulators response and request tab are not working. At least when I am using a custom action.json.

For me I am not sure if all have this problem or only some. That are using an custom action sdk. Or is it a problem only because something of my action.json is maybe not 100% correct configured.

here is the action.json:

```
  {
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "testApp"
    },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "open special manager",
            "open s p m"
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "types": [],
  "conversations": {
    "testApp": {
      "name": "testApp",
      "url": "https://572e66a2.ngrok.io/",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2,
      "in_dialog_intents": [
        {
          "name": "actions.intent.NO_INPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

here is a picture of the request:
[image]
As you can see it is only the dummy content in request tab anyway if the chat is working.

The response tab is completly empty. But the messages and voice is correctly working. Also on my google home.

Does anybody have an idea? I will add of course more debug informations if necessary. Can it be trouble with the response or request messages from my server? 
But actually the messages, they are working...

Comment: Hi! Are you not seeing a "DEBUG" tab to the right of the "AUDIO" tab? That should hold the exact request/response payloads for the dialog. Have you tried using Dialogflow and seeing if the "DEBUG" tab is visible then?